# How can I include images inside a text or paragraph

Tags: html, pdf, xsl-fo

Not sure about the right terminology as I'm rather new to xsl:fo. I'm creating some stylesheets to convert html pages to pdf, and all works pretty ok with exception to 'in paragraph' images. I'm having a few paragraphs including icons and I like to convert these to xsl:fo.

The html looks as follows :

```
<p>This is a sentence with some icons, like <img src="icon_up"/>, <img src="icon_down"/>, and <img src="icon_right"/></p>
```

which looks like

```
This is a sentence with some icons, like [u], [d], and [r]
```

I'm using these templates to convert to pdf (using Altova XML / FOP)

```
<xsl:template match="p">
    <fo:block font-size="12pt" line-height="15pt" space-after="12pt">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*|text()"/>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="img[parent::p]">
   <fo:external-graphic src="{@src}" width="100%" content-width="scale-to-fit" scaling="uniform" content-height="100%"/>
</xsl:template>
```

but my result is as follows :

```
This is a sentence with some icons, like 
[u]
, 
[d]
, and 
[r]
```

So, how do I get it in one line rather than cascading down ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formatting object `fo:external-graphic` has two pairs of dimensions:

- **`width` and `height`** define the *allocated area* for the image (informally, they define a "window" or "hole" through which the image is seen)

  - percentages are relative to the width and height of a line
  - if not set to a fixed value or a percentage, they default to the corresponding value of the other couple of parameters
- **`content-width` and `content-height`** define the *size* of the image

  - percentages are relative to the intrinsic size of the image (pixel width / resolution, pixel height / resolution)

If `width` and `height` define a rectangle smaller than the one defined by `content-width` and `content-height`, then just a portion of the image will be visible; in the opposite situation, the allocated area will be occupied only partially by the image (you can find the complete, formal definitions in the [XSL-FO specifications, § 6.6.5 fo:external-graphic](http://www.w3.org/TR/xsl/#fo_external-graphic)).

Your original template has:

```
<fo:external-graphic src="{@src}" width="100%" .../>
```

so the allocated area for each image has a width equal to the **100% of the line width**, pushing the following content in the next lines.

In order to have smaller images in the same line as the text surrounding them you can use `content-width` and `content-height`, setting them to either a fixed value (e.g. `"1cm"`) or a percentage relative to their intrinsic size (as you did in your self answer), and leave `width` and `height` to their default value.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, I found the solution in the meantime, like this is works :

```
<xsl:template match="img[parent::p]">
<fo:inline> <fo:external-graphic src="{@src}" content-width="80%" scaling="uniform"/></fo:inline>
</xsl:template>
```